# Branch has no meta data when trying to open branch link using open URL

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have an imessage app, in which i would like to attach branch url to the message. So when user clicks on the message, it should redirect to the original app (not to the mesaage app) with metadata.

It is opening the app but with out any metadata. But when i click it gives the metadata.

But programatically opening the app using open URL, doesn't gives me the meta data.

Can you please help me how to achieve this

Comment: Alex from Branch.io: could you provide some additional details? Code examples and a short animated GIF or video of what you are describing would be very helpful!

Comment: self.extensionContext?.openURL(<ShouldBeBranchURL>, completionHandler: { (success) in })  .

 It opens the app, but the app didn't get the metadata. 

But i observe that , if use Branch.getInstance().resetUserSession() , i am getting the meta data.        

Branch.getInstance().initSessionWithLaunchOptions([:], andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
            Branch.getInstance().resetUserSession()
 <Handle Link Using Params>
}

Comment: calling  Branch.getInstance().resetUserSession() works in some case cases but not all the cases.

Comment: Even calling resetUserSession is working sometime but not in all the cases

Comment: Hmm...`resetUserSession()` is an internal method you should not usually need to call. We haven't seen many live implementations of an iMessage app routing to the parent app yet, so this may be a new issue. Could you [submit an Integrations ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so we can dig in further and see what is going on?

Comment: @AlexBauer I have also this type of problem. Did Branch resolve it? Or still we need to send an integration ticket?

Comment: @Alleria I don't think we ever got a ticket from this, so it may not have been investigated yet. Please feel free to send something in, and then we can update with an answer here

Comment: Ok thanks very much